# How to ensure that all elements are loaded on an html page, and then we perform some modifications on elements in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, esri, arcgis-js-api

This would be a generic question asked a number of times before. The reason why i am asking this is because i did use the on ready call back in jquery and it did not modify the placeholder of my element "search_input"

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $("#search_input").attr('placeholder','New data that will be shown');
}
```

This is because the CSS is applied on the id "search_input" before it is loaded. I have tried everything but nothing seems to work.

Any ideas?

Note  : I am working on ArcGIS Javascript to applications using ERSI maps . The issue i face is occurs when I load a search bar through javascript, which takes time to load the search bar. But my html page calls the on ready callback before this script is loaded. Hence, I face this issue. I am unable to solve this and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to run the `attr` function in a callback on your search bar function, not on a `ready` event.

Comment: @Meghna, Can you please share your HTML?

Comment: @isherwood  It worked! I was trying that just a while back but i guess the code was incorrect. Thank you!! I have also posted the solution below!

Comment: @MeghnaNatraj Great. Nice to hear that. How did you solve it?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I have posted the solution below. I guess I am new to Dojo so didn't realize I need to use the search callback!

Comment: @MeghnaNatraj Just saw your "Wumpus World" in your Github, is it possible to ask something related to that?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed this in my code using this,

```
search.on("load", function () {
//push all the sources
  var sources = search.sources;
  sources.push(addSources("ABC","ABC","eg : ABC",1));
  sources.push(addSources("XYZ","XYZ","eg: XYZ",1));
  search.set("sources", sources);

  //Adding the placeholder here, as the search bar is loaded with sources only at this point of the execution
  //Hence, we can modify the CSS only after this point.
  $("#search_input").attr('placeholder','Search Tree Data');
  });
```

You cannot modify the CSS anywhere in the code. It has to be modified only when the search bar has been loaded with all its sources. I tried adding a $document.ready(function(){}); or adding the css at the end of the body. Nothing worked because we are using a different javascript library/toolkit here - Dojo. Hence, we can only performs operations based on how the data is loaded or when call backs are called in Dojo. and not in normal HTML javascript to jQuery.

Comment: So what's `search` here, exactly?